# How to give each button individual values

Tags: c#, button

I have this program which makes buttons move across the screen. What I'm trying to achieve is that all the buttons can go in all different directions. The problem is that I can't seem to find a clean solution to my goal. This is my code so far.

```
private void MoveTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KeerBewogen++;

            foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
            {
                if (KeerBewogen == 150)
                {
                    RichtingX = rnd.Next(-1, 2);
                    RichtingY = rnd.Next(-1, 2);
                    KeerBewogen = 0;
                }

                button.Location = new Point(button.Location.X + RichtingX, button.Location.Y + RichtingY);

                if (button.Location.X == 1 || button.Location.Y == 1)
                {
                    RichtingX = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                    RichtingY = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                }

                if (button.Location.X == 550 || button.Location.Y == 750)
                {
                    RichtingX = rnd.Next(-1, 0);
                    RichtingY = rnd.Next(-1, 0);
                }
            }

            if (btnEend1.Location.X == 1 || btnEend1.Location.Y == 1)
            {
                RichtingX = rnd.Next(0, 2);
                RichtingY = rnd.Next(0, 2);
            }

            if (btnEend1.Location.X == 550 || btnEend1.Location.Y == 750)
            {
                RichtingX = rnd.Next(-1, 0);
                RichtingY = rnd.Next(-1, 0);
            }
        }
```

With this code the buttons do move across the screen at different angles, but they ALL go the same way.
Is there a way to set the RichtingY and RichtingX individualy for each button?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for a full answer, but the best way I can think of would be to make your own class MovingButton which is derived from Button. MovingButton could have properies like RichtingX and RichtingY, which would be unique to each instance. In addition it could have methods such as "ChangeDirection".

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Mike! I'll try it as soon as I got back to coding. I'll let you know if it works out.

Comment: don't share the same instance of `Random` for all buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the relation between a button and the X,Y move values
For example:

```
Dictionary<Button,Tuple<int,int>> angledict = new Dictionary<Button,Tuple<int,int>>();
```

Then add each button to the dictionary:

```
foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
    angleDict.Add(button, new Tuple<int,int>(0,0))
}
```

To update the button's location and change the X,Y values:

```
foreach (Button button in this.Controls.OfType<Button>()) {
    **...**
    var kvpair = angleDict(button);
    button.Location = new Point(button.Location.X + kvpair.Value.Item1, button.Location.Y + kvpair.Value.Item2);
    **...**
    angleDict(button) = new Tuple<int,int>(rnd.Next(2),rnd.Next(2));
}
```